# Создать директорию с именем текущей даты

Tags: linux, bash, variable

Нужно создать директорию как текущая дата.
Написал такую функцию

```
cddate () {
  local newdir
  newdir=$(date +%Y.%m.%d)
  mkdir $newdir
  cd $newdir
}
```

Можно сделать это же без использование переменной?

Comment: `$ mkdir $(date +%Y.%m.%d); cd $(date +%Y.%m.%d)`

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin  Ваш вариант не сработает, если между двумя командами сменится день.

Comment: @Ainar-G, ну если запускать в 23:59:59, то да.

Comment: Можно, но не нужно, потому что будет race condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если это нужно сделать в функции без объявления переменной, то выглядеть это будет так:

```
cddate () {
  mkdir "${1:-`date '+%Y-%d-%m'`}"
  cd "${1:-`date '+%Y-%d-%m'`}"
}
```

При простом вызове функции будет создан каталог с текущей датой и переход в него.

```
[root@...]# cddate
mkdir 2019-28-10
cd 2019-28-10
```

При вызове можно указать первый параметр как имя создаваемого каталога:

```
[root@...]# cddate 12143
mkdir 12143
cd 12143
```

---

Как говорилось в комментариях - это может не сработать при вызове функции во время замены календарного дня в 23:59:59

Comment: Тогда уж функцию лучше определить так  mkdir "${1:-`date '+%Y-%d-%m'`}"; cd "$_"

Answer (score 3):

На случай возможной смены дня или другой единицы времени, можно не вычислять аргумент заново, а дублировать из первой команды. Проверить работоспособность можно на наносекундах:

```
mkdir `date +%Y.%m.%d_%N`; cd `date +%Y.%m.%d_%N`
```

> bash: cd: 2019.10.28_262358027: No such file or directory

```
mkdir `date +%Y.%m.%d_%N`; cd $_; basename `pwd`
```

> 2019.10.28_799225840